# How to Hide/Show the checkbox according to condition

Tags: javascript

I want to hide the all checkboxes in my listing page according to the condition.
when i select any value from dropdown then all checkboxes should be visible.

Comment: ng-hide="condition". For more information see documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide

Comment: What you tried? learn [How Do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you should specify if you are using Angular (2/4/5) or AngularJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template do something like this.

```
<div *ngIf="yourBoolean">
  your check boxes goes in here
</div>
```

you can show hide your check boxes by changing the value of yourBoolean.

hope this helps.

Comment: I would recommend ng-show/ng-hide as that uses CSS to view/show the element. ng-if removes it from the DOM.